# Alternative to doing lots of calculations in constructor - scala

Tags: scala, constructor

I'm learning scala for a new project, aiming for immutability and functional style wherever possible.

One of the objects I'm creating takes a number of inputs in its constructor, then repeatedly applies a large number of calculations to generate the relevant outputs, which are stored as fields on the object.

While the calculations are performed and their results added to a mutable `ListBuffer` internally, everything else about the object is immutable - once created you can't change any of the input values and running the calculations again would obviously produce the same result.

However, it doesn't seem right to me to have so many calculations in the constructor. The only way around it I can see is to have the calculated values be `var`s and provide a `run` method which performs the calculations - but then this method could be called multiple times, which would be pointless.

Is it actually OK style to do a lot in a scala constructor? There's no calls to the DB for example, just internal calculations. Or is there some pattern for this?

Here's the basic idea in very very simple form:

```
class Foo(val x:Int, val y:Int, calculations:List[Calculation]) {
  val xHistory = new collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]()
  val yHistory = new collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]()

  calculations.map { calc => calc.perform(this) }.foreach { result => 
    xHistory += result.x 
    yHistory += result.y
  }
}
```

Basically I want the inputs wrapped in a handy instance of a `Foo` object so I can pass it to the various calculation strategies (each of which may need a different combination of inputs).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Work inside the constructor

Usually I do expensive stuff inside the constructor. But note that the comments mention that constructor code might be less optimized by (insert Java implementation here for which this is correct). Also read the next paragraph if you have a multi-threaded application.

### Delayed Init

<strike>I don't know anything that might be wrong with doing much work inside a constructor.</strike>

As noted inside the comments, there may be problems with code running inside the constructor concerning concurrency. Therefor the `DelayedInit` trait has been introduced in Scala 2.8.0. Problems with of this kind occur for example when working with Swing GUI elements.

> The `DelayedInit` trait provides another tool to customize
>   initialization sequences of classes and objects. If a class or object
>   inherits from this trait, all its initialization code is packed in a
>   closure and forwarded as an argument to a method named delayedInit
>   which is defined as an abstract method in trait DelayedInit.
>
> Implementations of delayedInit have thus full freedom when to execute
>   the initialization code. For instance, Scala’s new `App` trait stores
>   all initialization sequences in an internal buffer and executes them
>   when the object’s main method is called.

### Lazy Constructs

To delay the computations in a different way, you can use the following methods, which also solve the concurrency issue:

- You can use `lazy val` members, which will get computed once they are first requested.
- If you compute a sequence of expensive objects, you might want to use a "lazy" data structure like `Stream`. This is like a `List` that computes the next element only on demand. Thus at some point in time, only the initial part of the `Stream` that has already been accessed has been computed.

### Indication to use `lazy`

Another consideration you might want to do is whether the computed values **will** get used at all. If they might not be needed, then using the lazy methods I described is the way to go. On the other hand, if you definately access these expensive memebers, in my opinion there is nothing wrong with doing the computations inside a constructor and using lazy members might add unescessary computational overhead.

#### Note regarding OP example

It's not ok to do dangerous things inside the constructor; like letting references to the partially constructed object escape the constructor (via a `this`-reference). The example inside the OP does this with `calc.perform(this)`. This "potential bug" cannot be fixed with the following suggestions.

Comment: I remember reading something in Effective Java about the dangers of calling methods external to an object in its constructor as it could provide access to that object in an inconsistent, half-constructed state.

Comment: Which is exactly what I'm doing here by passing in those calculation strategy objects.

Comment: I guess that the danger is to make a partially constructed object available; thus passing out the `this` reference. Indeed you are passing a `this` reference to another method in your example. I think this is dangerous in general and might also cause problems when using `lazy val`. Maybe the best solution is to refactor your code to avoid this situation; like break the object apart into the things that get passed out (and must be constructed already) and the things that depend on those.

Comment: @Russell Quintessential, in your question you asked whether its ok to do much stuff inside the constructor - I think that's ok. Doing dangerous things inside the constructor (like letting a `this` reference escape) is not ok.

Comment: My fault for a badly worded question. If you add that to your answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Russel I've added a clarification about this.

Comment: Wasn't the whole point of introducing the `App` trait in 2.9 to avoid doing calculations in the constructor, because the JVM can't optimize them? The docs on `Application` mention this.

Comment: Constructors can't handle multithreaded code, nor are they subject to all optimizations available to normal code. So there _are_ problems with running heavy computations on a constructor.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge See my comment. The optimization is a factor, yes, but the problems with multithreading were much more vexing -- you'll see lots of questions about problems with actors that were due to the use of `Application`.

Comment: Wow, I'm glad I checked back on this question, the answer has changed a bit since I was last here!

Comment: I can't seem to get `DelayedInit` to work - sbt complains that the class that extends it doesn't define method `delayedInit`. Will put this in another question unless anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Got it working. `DelayedInit` was just the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

What about creating a factory method that performs all necessary computations and returns new immutable instance prepopulated with computed values? You can use companion object to have factory method close actual object.

```
object Foo {
    def create(input: ...) {
        val output = //long running computations
        new Foo(output)
    }
}

class Foo(val output: ...)
```

You might want to hide `Foo` `class` constructor as suggested by *@Nicolas*:

```
class Foo private (val output: ...)
```

Now you can write:

```
val foo: Foo = Foo.create(input)
```

Comment: You should set the class Foo's constructor as private, no?

Comment: What I'm after is being able to set the inputs on the class in its constructor, then have methods in the class itself to do calculations based on them. As various calculations are going to need various bits of input at different times I wanted the object as a handy container for them. I'll add a code example to try to better explain myself.

Comment: @Nicolas: not sute, maybe somebody wants to create a raw instance of `Foo` without actually computing anything (e.g. for testing?) Nevertheless I added version with `private` constructor for completness.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to encapsulate the calculations in a value initializer

```
class Foo(arg1:String, arg2:String){

val (x, y, z) = {  //tedious calculation using inputs
                        (result1, result2, result:3)}

}
```

You can make the values produced lazy if consuming them may be optional, or if it's more sensible to take the performance hit of your calculation at first use time rather than upon construction.